# How to get byte value from IsolatedStorageSettings?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Like in Title What I'm trying to do is get byte(type of) value from IsolatedStorageSettings

```
IsolatedStorageSettings isoSett = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (isoSett.Contains("level") && isoSett.Contains("sound"))
        {
            bool dzwiek = (bool)isoSett["sound"];
            byte poziom = (byte)isoSett["level"];// here i get InvalidCastException
        }
        else 
        {
            isoSett.Add("level", 1);
            isoSett.Add("sound", true);
            isoSett.Save();
        }
```

How should i retrive this value?
Thanks for advance:)

**EDIT:** Nothing else is write under this InvalidCastException

Comment: What is the message of the `InvalidCastException`? What does it think it is trying to cast from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should dig in with the debugger and see what `isoSett["level"]` *actually is*.

hypothetically it is an int the way you saved it, but that shouldn't cause that cast to fail.  unless level was a much bigger number and you overflow byte?

Comment: yea man that was problem cast from int to byte. I didn't know that number 1 by default is int.
Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

#### Save Generic Object From Isolated Storage

```
public void Save<T>(string fileName, T item)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, storage))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, item);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Load Generic Object From Isolated Storage

```
public T Load<T>(string fileName)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, storage))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Calling Load

```
string fileName = "SampleTest.txt";
byte level = 1;
Save<byte>(fileName, level);
byte value = Load<byte>(fileName);
```

Comment: this works but I don't need to make new file for contain only 2 short information, thats why i want to use IsolatedStorageSettings

Comment: Yea....I understand. Why don't you make an object and have it contain the level and sound. Then you save this object to a single entry in the isolated storage. Doing it this way you have more control and you can save different objects to different locations.